# EasyPaginate with Touchwipe

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to get Touchwipe to connect with EasyPaginate so when I swipe left for instance it would be the same as clicking on the "next" pager button, I just can't seem to find the parameter from Jquery Easypaginate that would allow me to touchwipe to next pager, please see below what I have got so far, and thanks so much in advance for your comments/help,
Michel

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/easypaginate.js"></script>   
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js"></script>  


              <script>

                $(document).ready(function() {


                   $('ul#items').touchwipe({
                       wipeLeft: function() { 
          // not sure what easyPaginate parameter should go below to trigger the touchwipe?
                           $('#pagination .prev').easyPaginate(); 
                        },
                       wipeRight: function() { 
                           $('#pagination').easyPaginate(next); 
                       },
        // wipeUp: function() { alert("up"); },
        // wipeDown: function() { alert("down"); },
         min_move_x: 20,
         min_move_y: 20,
         preventDefaultEvents: true
    }); 
                });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which was on Stack Overflow already:

$("#pagination .next").click(); // selector for you 'next' btn